# Convert positive square wave to positive-negative

Tags: pwm

I am looking for a way to convert a square wave coming from a microcontroller with voltage range from 0V to 5V, to a voltage range from -12V to +12V. The frequency of a square wave will vary from few Hz to few MHz.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a MAX232 RS-232 driver?

Comment: What voltage source will you have available?

Comment: @Majenko, I was thinking the same thing, but I believe the MAX232 just uses a voltage doubler. So he'd only get +/-10V (minus a diode drop).

Comment: @DanLaks These are the three voltages avaliable: 5V and +-12V.

Comment: A dual supply op-amp as a comparator would do the trick then.

Comment: Ofcourse... How did I forget about that... Thanks!

Comment: You would be better off to use a dedicated comparator IC. There are multiple issues with using an op amp as a comparator, especially if you intend to go MHz territory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an op-amp, powered from +/-15 V rails to both amplify and level shift the 0 to 5V square wave: -

[image]

The circuit above is called an op-amp summer (or adder or mixer) in that two  analogue values are mathematically added. If V1 is the input waveform centred at 2.5 volts, the action of applying - 2.5 volts to V2 will result in the output, Vout being level shifted to make a square wave symettrical about 0V.

Choosing Rf appropriately will ensure the square wave amplitude is 24 volts p-p. Use a fast op-amp to preserve the speeds of the edges of the sq wave.

One more thing, the circuit above inverts the square wave so if duty cycle is important, this will appear inverted too.

Comment: For this circuit to work in the MHz region, an op amp with a pretty high gain bandwith and slew rate will necessary.

Comment: @MattYoung I totally agree

Comment: Yeah, duty cycle is important.

Comment: @Golaž then invert the 0-5V sq wave before feeding the high-speed op-amp. I'll also add that this method gives a precise +12V and -12V output rather than lose about half a volt or so in a push-pull stage. This may not be that important of course.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider a simple BJT level shifter-driver as below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fivGHT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit- How it works:

When the input is high (close to Vcc - +5V in your case), Q4 is off, R4 pulls the base of Q2 down, Q2 is off and R1 pulls the base of Q1 and Q3 high. The output will thus be about 11.4V.

When the input is low (relative to Vcc - +5V in your case), current flows through R2, turning on Q4. Current flows through R3 and turns on Q2, pulling the bases of Q1 and Q3 low. The output will thus be about -11.4V.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit how it works?

Comment: @Golaž Please see edit.

Comment: should resistors be 1watt?